# Do I miss anything if I don't play the DLC campaigns before New Game+?

Tags: darksiders-2

I'm just about to complete my first playthrough of Darksiders II, and I'd like to start New Game+ as soon as I can, but I haven't played through the DLC campaigns (Argul's Tomb, The Abyssal Forge, The Demon Lord Belial).  I have all of the DLC available through Steam.

Do I miss anything (such as legendary equipment) if I start New Game+ without playing through these campaigns first?